# Only script apps may use password auth praw

Tags: python, praw

I'm trying to make a Reddit reposter but every time I run the program it says
"prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException: unauthorized_client error processing request (Only script apps may use password auth)"

```
def bot_login():
print('Logging in...')
r = praw.Reddit(username='**',
                password='**',
                client_id='**',
                client_secret='**',
                user_agent='None')
print('Logged in as user: "'+str(r.user.me())+'"')
print("------------------------------------------------------------------")
return r
```

any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You probably made a web app on the reddit applications page on accident. Reddit only allows script type web applications to use password authentication for security purposes.

**To Fix:**

1. Go to https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps
2. Choose the "script" type application
   [(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gvmt.png)
3. Recreate your application